# show category banner image on product pages woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Woocommerce Category Plugin, which enables the assignment of a banner image to a specific category, this is then brought out in the header of the page should the user be viewing a category page.

However I would like to also show the same banner once someone has clicked through on a specific product page.

The code of the plugin is below, I do hope someone can help or at least point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks in advance for all your input

Plugin code

```
<?php 
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

if ( ! class_exists( 'WCB_Category_Banner' ) ) :

class WCB_Category_Banner {

public function __construct() {

    // Add Scripts and styles       
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'admin_scripts_and_styles' ) );

    // Add the fields to the product cateogry taxonomy 
    add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', array( $this, 'wcb_product_cat_taxonomy_custom_fields' ), 10, 2 );  

    // Save the changes made on the product category taxonomy 
    add_action( 'edited_product_cat', array( $this, 'wcb_product_cat_save_taxonomy_custom_fields'), 10, 2 );  

    // Add a banner image based on category taxonomy image
    add_action( 'woo_header_inside', array( $this, 'wcb_show_category_banner'), 30 );
}

/*
*   Adds necessary admin scripts
*/
public function admin_scripts_and_styles() {

    // Get current screen attributes
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    if ( $screen != null and $screen->id == "edit-product_cat" ) {

        // Adds WP Modal Window References          
        wp_enqueue_media();

        // Enque the script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wcb_admin_script',
            plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/wcb-admin.js',
            array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true
        );

        // Add Style
        wp_enqueue_style( 
            'wcb_admin_styles', 
            plugins_url( '/assets/css/wcb-admin.css', __FILE__ )
        );
    }
}

/*
*   Adds default option values
*/  
public function wcb_product_cat_taxonomy_custom_fields( $tag ) {

    // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing  
    $t_id = $tag->term_id; // Get the ID of the term you're editing  
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" ); // Do the check  

    // Get banner image
    if ( isset( $term_meta['banner_url_id'] ) and $term_meta['banner_url_id'] != '' )
        $banner_id = $term_meta['banner_url_id'];
    else 
        $banner_id = null;

    // Get banner link 
    if ( isset( $term_meta['banner_link'] ) and $term_meta['banner_link'] != '' )
        $banner_link = $term_meta['banner_link'];
    else 
        $banner_link = null;

    ?>  

    <tr class="form-field banner_url_form_field">  
        <th scope="row" valign="top">  
            <label for="banner_url"><?php _e('Banner Image'); ?></label>  
        </th>  
        <td>  
            <fieldset>
                <a class='wcb_upload_file_button button' uploader_title='Select File' uploader_button_text='Include File'>Upload File</a>
                <a class='wcb_remove_file button'>Remove File</a>
                <label class='banner_url_label' ><?php if ( $banner_id != null ) echo basename( wp_get_attachment_url( $banner_id ) ) ?></label>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>              
                <img class="cat_banner_img_admin" src="<?php if ( $banner_id != null ) echo wp_get_attachment_url( $banner_id ) ?>" />
            </fieldset>

            <input type="hidden" class='wcb_image' name='term_meta[banner_url_id]' value='<?php if ( $banner_id != null ) echo $banner_id; ?>' />
        </td>  
    </tr>  

    <tr class="form-field banner_link_form_field">  
        <th scope="row" valign="top">  
            <label for="banner_link"><?php _e('Banner Image Link'); ?></label>  
        </th>  
        <td>  
            <fieldset>  
                <input type="url" name='term_meta[banner_link]' value='<?php if ( $banner_link != null ) echo $banner_link ?>' />       
                <label class="banner_link_label" for="banner_link"><em>Where users will be directed if they click the banner.</em></label>      
            </fieldset>
        </td>  
    </tr> 

<?php  
}

// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s)  
public function wcb_product_cat_save_taxonomy_custom_fields( $term_id ) {  

    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {  
        $t_id = $term_id;  
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" );  
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );  

            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ){  
            if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ){  
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];  
            }  
        }  
        //save the option array  
        update_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta );  
    }
}

// Retreives and print the category banner
public function wcb_show_category_banner() {
    global $woocommerce;
    global $wp_query;

    // Make sure this is a product category page
    if ( is_product_category() ) {

        $cat_id = $wp_query->queried_object->term_id;
        $term_options = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$cat_id" ); 

        // Ge the banner image id
        if ( $term_options['banner_url_id'] != '' )
            $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $term_options['banner_url_id'] ); 

        // Exit if the image url doesn't exist
        if ( !isset( $url ) or $url == false )
            return;

        // Get the banner link if it exists
        if ( $term_options['banner_link'] != '' )
            $link = $term_options['banner_link'];

        // Print Output


        if ( isset( $link ) )
            echo "<a href='" . $link . "'>"; 

        if ( $url != false ) 
            echo "<div id=\"mainslider\"><img src='" . $url . "' class='category_banner_image' /></div>";
            echo '  
                <div id="welcome" style="width:300px; min-height:210px;">
                <div class="whitebanner">
                <h2>Give Us a Call</h2></div>
                <p class="welcometext"><strong>Janet Morley & Jill Perkins</strong></p>
                <p class="welcomedetails">Tel: +44 (15395) 64247<br/>
                Tel: +44 (16268) 88069<br/>
                Mobile: +44 (77329) 26787<br/>
                </p>
                </div> 
                ';

        if ( isset( $link ) )
            echo "</a>";
    }
}  
}

endif;

new WCB_Category_Banner();

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to think on what happens if one product has many categories, and if it has, which one will display?

We need to create and array of category id's and randomly select one, right?

So:

1. Create an array to hold your id's
2. Get all categories of current product
3. Get one of this ids randomly
4. Obtain the corresponding banner off that id

   ```
    $termArray =  array();
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, "sectores");

    //insert id's in to array
    foreach ($terms as $id) {
       $termArray[] = $id->term_id;
    }

   //get random id
   $randomId = array_rand($termArray);

    //final ID
   $cat_id = $termArray[$randomId];

   //Get values from database
   $banner = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$cat_id" );

   $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $banner['banner_url_id'] ); 
   $link = $banner['banner_link'];

   echo '<a href="'.$link.'">';
   echo '<img src="'.$url.'">';
   echo "<a>";
   ```

Comment: The above code place under the 3rd to last } works perfectly once your alter the following line from
 $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, "sectores");
to 
$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, "product_cat");

Although it does show the correct banner image, the link seemed to be the page you are already, as this is not relevant for my needs I class this as being resolved.